# How many proofs of the Weil conjectures are there?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, weil-conjectures, nt.number-theory, soft-question

I hope this this is not seen as too much as jumping on the band-wagon, but here goes.

Deligne's proof of the last of the [Weil conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) is well-known and just part of a huge body of work that has lead to prizes, medals etc (wink wink). The other conjectures were proved by Dwork and Grothendieck. According to Wikipedia, Deligne gave a second proof, and then mentions three more proofs. However, it is unclear from what I read as to which of the conjectures they all prove - namely all of them, or just the Riemann hypothesis.

> So how many proofs of the complete set of Weil conjectures are there?

Comment: Deligne's l-adic proofs are really only variants of the same proof. Perhaps Kedlaya's p-adic proof is genuinely different.

Comment: My recollection is that Kedlaya's proof is modeled on Deligne's 2nd proof, using a $p$-adic cohomology theory.  Laumon's proof via $\ell$-adic Fourier transform is rather different from Deligne's proofs (or at least I remember it seeming so when I read it).

Comment: "...  or just the Riemann hypothesis." :)

Comment: What is your equivalence relation on proofs?  If someone came up with an ur-proof that specialized to multiple existing proofs, would that increase or decrease your count?

Comment: @Scott - Ideally an answer would not just state whether proofs are "the same" or not, but be informative as to how they differ or are similar. :-) @Martin - you know what I mean.

Comment: I would vote up Scott's comment 5 times if I could. His comment is a proof that the question makes no sense!

Comment: The Ramanujan conjecture (a consequence) can though be proven via  different methods (Weil conjecture, functoriality of the symmetric powers, Langlands duality between automorphic forms and Galois reps). The later two have not been achieved in the number field setting yet.

Comment: Oh, the duality is known for modular forms over $\mathbb{Q}$ for weight $k \geq 1$, only not for Maass-forms.

Comment: David, I'm not sure I know what you mean. The first two Weil conjectures are implicit in the third, and the known proofs all proceed by cohomology, so I'm not sure what a proof of "just" the Riemann hypothesis would look like.

Comment: It's not clear to me that the collection of all proofs of a statement forms a set. Perhaps it's more like a topological space up to homotopy, or a metric space (and then we should measure its magnitude and not its cardinality), or... 

Comment: @Qiaochu - clearly they form a type as in Martin-Löf type theory, which under the Homotopy Type Theory interpretation, does represent a homotopy type.

Comment: @Timothy - ah, I didn't know this, thanks.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan but the collection of all proofs of a statement published in a peer-reviewed journal is a set, right?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I guess that "just the Riemann hypothesis" means the statement about the eigenvalues of Frobenius acting on the $H^i$ of a smooth proper variety, and "all of then" means the full theory of weights : definition of mixed sheaves, how the 4 operations affect weights etc (from which you get the hard Lefschetz theorem, the decomposition theorem...).

So here is my understanding :

- Deligne's first proof : just the Riemann hypothesis.
- Deligne's second proof : the full package for $\ell$-adic complexes, using the same kind of ideas as his proof but improving them.
- Laumon's proof with the $\ell$-adic Fourier transform : It allows to simplify parts of Deligne's second proof, but does not replace all of it. More precisely, Laumon gives a shorter proof of theorem 3.2.3 of Deligne's "La conjecture de Weil II" that doesn't use section 2 of that paper, but he still needs results from section 1 (the calculation of the monodromy of lisse sheaves on curves in 1.8 and the fact that "most" irreducible lisse sheaves are pure proved in 1.5.1). Once you have theorem 3.2.3, it is pretty easy to deduce the rest of the "full package" from it, so Laumon doesn't say anything about that.
- Katz's proof : Katz gives a simpler proof of theorem 3.2.3 of Deligne's Weil II paper, or rather of a weakening of it that is enough to deduce the Riemann hypothesis and hard Lefschetz. It is not enough to deduce the full package immediately, although this can be done without too much pain. I am not very familiar with Katz's proof. It seems to be different from Deligne's and Laumon's proofs but to use the same kind of techniques as Deligne's proof. My impression is that it is more concrete that Deligne's proof.
  (Note : I am not convinced that the difference between "just the Riemann hypothesis" and "the full package" is so big. The reason is that, if you know the Riemann hypothesis, then you should be able to deduce the full package for complexes of geometric origin. But global Langlands tells us that, over a smooth curve over a finite field, every irreducible lisse sheaves is of geometric origin up to twisting by a rank 1 sheaf. So in a way everything is of geometric origin. The situation is very different over a number field, of course.)
- Kedlaya's proof : It is supposed to be modeled on Deligne's second proof modulo the simplification of Laumon, but of course the actual technical are different because Kedlaya uses p-adic coefficients. Also, he got the Riemann hypothesis but not the full package, because at the time the theory of relative p-adic coefficients was not fully developed. But now it is !
- Abe and Caro's proof : See http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.0662
  They develop the theory of weights for overholonomic D-modules with Frobenius structure on varieties over finite fields and obtain a full Weil II package for them (and even the Asterisque 100 extension, ie the theory of weights for perverse sheaves). They say in the introduction that their method is independent from Kedlaya's method.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! 

Comment: Perhaps in connection to Kedlaya's proof, one should also mention Faltings' sketch of a crystalline version of Weil II (using convergent F-isocrystals, and logarithmic geometry) in the Grothendieck Festschrift.

Comment: Brilliant, this is the sort of thing I was after, especially the approaches not detailed in Wikipedia, and their provenance.

Comment: @user31960 Do you know any english reference for Laumon's Proof?